# Is it possible to rotateX inside an already rotatedX

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I have a container containing 3 divs, a b and c. The container is rotatedX 90 deg so it is like the container is "laying on it's back".  Next I wanted to rotate the a, b and c divs so it would look like they were "standing up" again. But it does not seem like I can make that possible. I have a fiddle I have been playing with that maybe explains my problem better.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="a box"></div>
        <div class="b box"></div>
        <div class="c box"></div>        
    </div>
</div>

.container { position:relative; }
.inner-container { margin-left:100px; margin-top:100px; width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); left:0px; -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); position:absolute; }
.box { width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
.a.box { background-color:green; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto; }
.b.box { background-color:blue; top:0; left:0; }
.c.box { background-color:yellow; top:0; right:0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tyf5vdj2/2/

Comment: That's what I thought. Now when I try to rotate them -90deg, I still cannot see them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`transform-style: preserve-3d`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-style) on `.inner-container`

```css
.container { position:relative; -webkit-perspective: 1000;}
.inner-container { margin-left:100px; margin-top:10px; width:200px; height:200px; background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1); left:0px; -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg); position:absolute; -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d}
.box { width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg); }
.a.box { background-color:green; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; margin:auto;   transform: rotateX(45deg);}
.b.box { background-color:blue; top:0; left:0; }
.c.box { background-color:yellow; top:0; right:0; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="a box"></div>
        <div class="b box"></div>
        <div class="c box"></div>        
    </div>
</div>
```